# WPF Highlight searched text in richtextbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox, highlight

I am very new to WPF

Currently my custom richtextbox that display the text are separated from the mainpage in another xaml that contained the search textbox (with a searched button).

I am trying to highlight the texts (in richtextbox) that are searched from the search textbox  at the main page.

Is it still possible to to do that??

```
<!-- Search box at main xaml-->
                    <Grid Margin="15 5 5 5">
                        <TextBox x:Name="searchTB" local:FocusProperty.Value="{Binding SearchIsOpen}"
                    Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeRegular}" Padding="0 5 0 0">
                            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                                <!-- Clear text on Esc -->
                                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ClearSearchCommand}" Key="Esc" />
                                <!-- Search on enter -->
                                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" Key="Return" />
                            </TextBox.InputBindings>
                        </TextBox>
                        <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeRegular}" Text=" Search for a text" Foreground="DarkGray" Padding="0 11 0 0">

                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
```

Currently the search textbox allow me to filter the richtextbox when i hit enter.

```
 <local:CustomRichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" CustomText="{Binding text}"
                                                />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlighting keywords in a richtextbox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316449/highlighting-keywords-in-a-richtextbox-in-wpf)

Comment: So the question is "How to hightlight selected words in a WPF RichTextBox"?