# How do I get the color of words in a string in RichTextBox WPF C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I have a text in my `RichTextBox` and I want to check if any of the words are not in black. If not, then I want the color value.

Here is how I am trying to read each word but I don't know what to do to get the color.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b[\s,\.-:;]*");
string richText = new TextRange(RichTextBoxData.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBoxData.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
List<string> listofWords = regex.Split(richText).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();
//TextRange textRange = new TextRange(RichTextBoxData.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBoxData.Document.ContentEnd);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(richText))
{
    foreach (string words in listofWords)
    {
        //Check colour
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810368/c-sharp-wpf-colorize-specific-words-in-richtextbox-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# WPF colorize specific words in RichTextBox text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810368/c-sharp-wpf-colorize-specific-words-in-richtextbox-text)

Comment: The link you have provided is to set colour, I want to get the colour from a `RichTextBox` and that too in **RGB** format like **(255,124,15)**.